# css nth-child and classes

Tags: class, css, css-selectors

I've got a problem with the css nth-child selector.
I have a grid of 3x3 elemtens inside a container. Those elements have a class called `.square`.
With `.square:nth-child(3n+1)` I select every first element of the row and color it green.
With `.square:nth-child(3n+3)` I select every last element of the row and color it red.

This works fine, until there is any element(`<br>` for example) that is outputted before the grid. With every new `<br>`, the order moves up by one, as is the `<br>` was considered a `.square`.

As I understand the `.nth-child`, it should select every third element of the `.square` class. Why does it apply that to any element, and how can I achieve my inital goal?

Thanks in advance

http://www.hier-krieg-ich-alles.de/shop.php?cat=26491127728

The problem occurs on the boxes in the middle.

Comment: please push your code for better understanding

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you want [`nth-of-type`](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/).

Related selectors which you may find useful are `:first-of-type`, `:last-of-type`, `:nth-last-of-type` and `:only-of-type`.

Comment: Yes. To clarify, `nth-child` only counts elements, so `.classname:nth-child` selects elements that happen to have `classname` and also happen to be an nth child.

Comment: Yep, that's what the linked page says :) `nth-child` is commonly used because it was first released (as far as I'm aware) but it's actually only useful in limited situations; `nth-of-type` is far more useful, because it does what most people think `nth-child` does.

Comment: Quite. `first-child` was the first, actually. Oddly enough, there was not even a `last-child` in the beginning.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't there even was a difference. However, it doesn't solve my problem, nothing did change. I edited my post to include the live example, did I do something wrong or is this not the right approach?

Comment: Still using `nth-child` when I inspect it in Chrome. As a side note, `3n` is the same as `3n+3`

Comment: Yes, I'm unable to change it in the live-release environment, but I did test it in a similar preview, where as stated the problem still occured.

Comment: You're not selecting the elements you think you are. The CSS rules you want are `.cat_outer_frame:nth-of-type(3n) { margin-left: 0; margin-right: 2%; }` for the left column, then no style for the middle column (it inherits 1% margin from `.cat_outer_frame`, and finally `.cat_outer_frame:nth-of-type(3n+2) { margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 0; }` for the right hand column

Comment: Using your CSS, the problem is solved on the page I linked. I probably should've mentioned that, but I need this to work independently of any previous elements. As soon as the slider div is removed, the wrong elements are selected again. Maybe jQuery is a more solid solution in this case?

Comment: `:nth-of-type()` does not select by an element's class either!

Answer (score 0):

nth-child working only with html element, nth-child css don't know class and id, if you want set nth-child for class, add some custom attribute for that class using jquery..

like

```
jQuery('.square:nth-child(3n+3)').attr("act","dummy");
```

then use css

```
div[act='dummy']{
 border : 1px solid red;}
```